# Datatable select() - search for numeric pattern

Tags: vb.net, winforms, filter, datatable

im having a problem with the `Select()` method in my datatable.

If i want to search in my `DataTable` for multiple patterns (search function)

For string Columns the 'Like' works

```
Select(String.Format("Requester like '%{0}%'", tb_RequesterSearch.Text))
```

but i also need to check for Numeric patterns in my Numeric column

if i try something like

```
For Each drOrder As DataRow In dsDatabase.Tables("ProjektImport").Select(String.Format("PONumber like '%{0}%'", convert.toDouble(tb_POSearch.Text)))
     'Do something
Next
```

i always get the exception, that 'Like' is not supportet for Numeric columns.

Is there an equivalent function or a way to cast my column as string (only in the select)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIKE Expressions don't work on numeric columns. You could add an additional `varchar` column to your DataTable via `select-clause`(before it is filled)  or use following LINQ way:

```
Dim PONumber As Double
If Double.TryParse(tb_POSearch.Text, PONumber) Then
    Dim PONumber_Pattern As String = "*" & PONumber & "*"
    Dim query As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) =
        From row In dsDatabase.Tables("ProjektImport").AsEnumerable()
        Where DirectCast(row("PONumber"), Double).ToString Like PONumber_Pattern
        Select row
    If query.Any Then
        For Each row As DataRow In query
             ' Do whatever you want with this DataRow '
        Next
    End If
End If
```

Don't confuse the ADO.NET [LIKE Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) with the VB.NET's [LIKE-Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx), that i've used here to keep it simple and working. I could also have been used `String.Contains` or a `RegularExpression` to achieve the same, it's a trade-off between performance and flexibility.

Comment: Thanks alot Tim, as always a good answer, and problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
... dsDatabase.Tables("ProjektImport").Select(String.Format("PONumber = {0}", tb_POSearch.Text))
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but i only need to look for patterns, not whole numbers.. lets say the purchase order has 10 digits: i need to find any PO in the '45000xxxxx' gap or just searching for an explicit with 'xxxxxx4391' .. I know i could loop through each row and convert + check the value with contains.. but if possible, i wanna avoid this